# php display random image after time

Tags: php, wordpress

I have written this little code to display a random image from an array, but for some weird reason I cant figure out where I am going wrong. I have changed the code a few times but to no avail. I also had code before that would not need an array to show the pictures within a folder but have sadly lost it.

```
            <?php

        $images = array('red.turtle','justice.league','logan','kong.skull.island','alien.covenant','spider-man.homecoming','thor.ragnarok','star.wars.viii','xxx.the.return.of.xander.cage','the.lego.batman.movie','wonder.woman','beauty.and.the.beast','war.for.the.planet.of.the.apes','transformers.the.last.knight','kingsman.the.golden.circle','the.mummy','t2.trainspotting','split','the.salesman','the.lure');

        function randomImage() {
            $interval = 2; // seconds
            srand(floor(time() / $interval));
            ?>
            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/mov_pic/<?php $images[rand(0,19)]?>.jpg";
        <?php }; ?>

        </div>
```

ps. the interval value is only for coding purposes to see if the code was working.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're trying to reference your $images array out of scope. Try adding it to your function.

IE:

```
function randomImage() {
      $images = array('red.turtle','justice.league','logan','kong.skull.island','alien.covenant','spider-man.homecoming','thor.ragnarok','star.wars.viii','xxx.the.return.of.xander.cage','the.lego.batman.movie','wonder.woman','beauty.and.the.beast','war.for.the.planet.of.the.apes','transformers.the.last.knight','kingsman.the.golden.circle','the.mummy','t2.trainspotting','split','the.salesman','the.lure');
      echo $images[rand(0,19)];
 }
```

Comment: but I want to produce a random image say after say 2 seconds. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an "echo" before rand inside the images array:

```
<?php echo $images[rand(0,19)]?>
```

Comment: I also have to add the directory to is as well. sorry

Comment: I know, i just commented on the local of missing code. But remember that get_template_directory_uri is a wordpress function, not a native php function.

Answer (score 0):

your code is working but $images variable is not accessible in randomImage scope you have to call it as global inside randomImage function or pass it as function parameter.

Simple: https://3v4l.org/aJj31

Simpler: https://3v4l.org/DpHYF

```
<?php

$images = array('red.turtle','justice.league','logan','kong.skull.island','alien.covenant','spider-man.homecoming','thor.ragnarok','star.wars.viii','xxx.the.return.of.xander.cage','the.lego.batman.movie','wonder.woman','beauty.and.the.beast','war.for.the.planet.of.the.apes','transformers.the.last.knight','kingsman.the.golden.circle','the.mummy','t2.trainspotting','split','the.salesman','the.lure');

/**
 * Simplified randomImage
 * @param array $imageList List of images in array
 */
function randomImage($imageList) {
    $imageCount = count($imageList) - 1;

    echo $imageList[rand(0, $imageCount)];
}

randomImage($images);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to define the images, you can use `glob` to find all `jpg` files in your directory.

```
function randomImage()
{
    $directory = get_template_directory() . "/img/mov_pic";
    $images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");

    return !empty($images) ? get_template_directory_uri() . "/" . $images[array_rand($images)] . ".jpg" : "";
}

echo '<img src="' . randomImage() . '">';
```

Comment: this is what I have now - <?php
   
     function randomImage() {
    
     $directory = get_template_directory_uri() . "/img/mov_pic";
    
     $images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");
    
     return !empty($images) ? get_template_directory() . "/" . $images[array_rand($images)] . ".jpg" : "";
      
     }

     echo '<img src="' . randomImage() . '" width="984px" height="400px">';
    
    ?> - but still doesn't work and no delay set for next image

Comment: @scottiescotsman What doesn't work, and what kind of delay do you want?

Comment: the image doesn't view at all and I just want it to repeat every 10 seconds. thanks

Comment: @scottiescotsman Try to debug the code, what's the output of `$directory` and `$images`? run `var_dump($directory, $images);`. I also see that you are using `get_template_directory_uri` instead of  `get_template_directory` in the `glob` function. Why?

Comment: to your answer the $dir & $images are both null,,, hmm and changed the glob code back.

Comment: @scottiescotsman You are probably writing it in the wrong place. You should write it just before the `return` line.

Comment: string(86) "C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs/wp-content/themes/SimpleAs/img/mov_pic/wonder.woman.jpg" it lists all the pics ok all 19 of them but I think the first 2 got errors as think they are for the "." & ".." ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158464/discussion-between-htmhell-and-scottiescotsman).